# v4l2 overlay on Qt

Tags: qt5, v4l2, qtwidgets

We are working on a ov5640 sensor camera, we brought up the camera on our ARM platform(based on i.Mx6)  and we tested the camera using v4l2 overlay application. Now we need to use that v4l2 application in the Qt5.

Is any application explaining us the method to create the overlay application (v4l2) on Qt? It will be helpful. We want to show the overlay inside a Qt widget(640x480) widget.

Any reference source or if methodology means will be helpful.